# Handing throw using jest and supertest

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, jestjs, supertest

I am trying to handle exception use case with supertest and jest for the given code. I tried many things but unable to find the solution.

```
var serverless = require('serverless-http');
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/post', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        // Get user from dynamodb
        const id = 'random-user-id';
        const user = await DynamoDb.Scan({
            TableName: 'user_table',
            FilterExpression: 'id = :id',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':id': id,
            },
        }).catch(async (err) => {
            throw err;
        });

        console.log('user', user);
        return res.status(200).send();

    } catch (exception) {
        // Trying to handle this
        throw exception;
    }

});

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

Test case

```
test("should throw error on failing to get user from database", async () => {

    mockScan.mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            promise() {
                return Promise.reject({});
            },
        };
    });

    const response = await request
        .post(`/post`)
        .send();
});
```

On running the test, it is getting stuck and leading to

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed. This
> usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't
> stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with
> `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: You _can't_ handle that, it's a fundamental problem in your server code - there's an unhandled promise rejection which doesn't lead to any response, the request just hangs. See e.g. http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#use-promises for fixes.